# Converting date format of SQL Server with VBS

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

I'm trying to convert and display my date like from this 04 Jun 2017 to 2017-06-04. These are my codes. How do I do it?

```vb
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=PC01\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TEST","admin","admin"

sql = "select SAS_DIRECTOR_APPOINTMENT.DATE_OF_APPOINTMENT from SAS_DIRECTOR_APPOINTMENT where  SAS_DIRECTOR_APPOINTMENT.WIP_GUID='0000000003'"
rs.Open sql,conn

MsgBox rs.Fields(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If your `SAS_DIRECTOR_APPOINTMENT.DATE_OF_APPOINTMENT` column is not of an [appropriate **DATE** data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-and-time-types), change the design of your database.
2. Use [info about converting/formatting dates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) to come up with a SELECT statement that returns exactly what you want to output (hint "UsingConvertTo_ISO8601".
3. Never expect a function (e.q. `Pd()`) to spring into existence just because you call it in your code.
4. (After seeing your edit) There is is difference between "doing it right" and "somehow fixing it". Choose carefully which side you want to be on.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this :

```
<![CDATA[<% 
    response.write YEAR(Date()) & _ 
        "-" & Pd(Month(date()),2) & _ 
        "-" & Pd(DAY(date()),2) 
%>]]>
```

Comment: Do I need to change anything within the codes? I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: Erm. those are my codes in the post. After calling out the date from SQL server, I just want to put it in a variable and display the date using YYYY-MM-DD format. but i dont know how

Answer (score 0):

According to the OP the problem was fixed by using the [`CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) function with the [undocumented argument 23](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15555275/1630171).

```vb
sql = "declare @datetemp as date;" & _
      "set @datetemp = (select SAS_DIRECTOR_APPOINTMENT.DATE_OF_APPOINTMENT from SAS_DIRECTOR_APPOINTMENT where SAS_DIRECTOR_APPOINTMENT.WIP_GUID='0000000003');" & _
      "SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @datetemp, 23), 23"
```